# Допустимо ли использовать public readonly переменные?

Tags: c#, инкапсуляция, readonly, свойства

Задался вопросом, нормальная ли практика использовать `public readonly` поля или всё же лучше делать их `private readonly` и затем получать значение через свойство, хотя казалось бы инкапсуляция не ломается из-за `public readonly` поля. Или есть ещё какие-то варианты?

Comment: Не нарушит если это поле нужно для других классов, но лучше использовать get-only свойство или же с private/protected set'ом. Хотя мне на практике не приходилось использовать `public readonly`

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Свойства вполне справляются с предоставлением досупа к данным класса, зачем что то выдумывать?

Comment: Допустимо. Константы тоже бывают публичными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ограниченно допустимо.

Нужно помнить, что открыв однажды поле, вы больше не сможете его убрать без потери бинарной совместимости со старым кодом, в то время как для свойства доступны варианты.

Однако, если класс никогда не используется из других сборок (т.е. является internal) - публичные поля в нём использовать допустимо.

Comment: а какие варианты доступны для свойства?

Comment: @Grundy реализовать его альтернативным образом, естественно